# Is it possible to say that "there exist exactly $x$ elements in a domain of discourse"?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I was wondering how it would be possible to say that there exist 'exactly' $x$ elements within our domain of discourse (without using the uniqueness quantifier?) $x$ can be any positive integer, but it must be a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some possible ways to make these kinds of numerical claims in general. In addition to claims involving 'exactly $n$' I'll also cover 'at least n' claim and 'at most n' claims, since thewy can all be realted to each other.

**'At least $n$' (Method 1)**

"There is at least $1$ object" : $\exists x \ x=x$ (most logics do not allow a simple $\exists x$ as a claim so we add the dummy $x=x$.  Also note that most logics *assume* there is at least one object in the domain, so you don't have to use any symbolization at all!)

"There are at least $2$ objects" : $\exists x \exists y  \ x \not = y$

"There are at least $3$ objects" : $\exists x \exists y \exists z ( x \not = y \land x \not = z \land y \not = z)$

Etc.

Note that with this method you need to use $n \choose 2$ non-identity claims so that increases rather quickly (e.g. to express there are at least $10$ objects, we would need $45$ non-identity statements!  ... can we improve on that? Yes! But first let's discuss 'at most':

**'At most $n$' (Method 1)**

One method to do 'at most $n$' is to deny 'at least $n+1$'. So:

"There is at most $1$ object": $\neg \exists x \exists y \ x \not = y$

If you bring the negation inside, this is equivalent to: $\forall x \forall y \ x = y$

"There are at most $2$ objects": $\neg \exists x \exists y \exists z (x \not = y \land x \not = z \land y \not = z)$

Again, bringing the negation inside you get:

$\forall x \forall y \forall z (x = y \lor x = z \lor y = z)$

Etc.

OK, so here we get even more (non-)identity statements: $n+1 \choose 2$. Later we will see how we can do this more efficiently, but first:

**'Exactly $n$' (Method 1)**

One method is to recognize that 'Exactly $n$' is equivalent to 'at least $n$ *and* at most $n$'. Doing a straightforward conjunction, we thus get:

"There is exactly $1$ object" : $\exists x x=x \land \neg \exists x \exists y \ x \not = y$

or, equivalently: $\exists x \ x=x \land \forall x \forall y \ x = y)$

"There are exactly $2$ objects" : $\exists x \exists y \ x \not = y \land \neg \exists x \exists y \exists z (x \not = y \land x \not = z \land y \not = z)$

or, equivalently: $\exists x \exists y \ x \not = y \land \forall x \forall y \forall z (x = y \lor x = z \lor y = z)$

Etc.

**'Exactly $n$' (Method 2)**

OK, so these claims get really big really fast. Can we do better? Yes. Instead of just conjuncting the 'at least' and 'at most' claims, let's integrate these two ideas: To say there are exactly $n$ objects, we can say that there are $n$ different objects ... but no others:

"There is exactly $1$ object" : $\exists x (x=x \land \neg \exists y \ x \not = y)$

And now we can get rid of the 'dummy' $x=x$ as well, so we get $\exists x \neg \exists y \ x \not = y$

or, equivalently: $\exists x \forall y \ x = y$

"There are exactly $2$ objects" : $\exists x \exists y (x \not = y \land \neg \exists z (z \not = x \land z \not = y))$

or, equivalently: $\exists x \exists y (x \not = y \land \forall z (z = x \lor z = y))$ (This is Eric Wofsey's example for 'exactly $2$')

"There are exactly $3$ objects" : $\exists x \exists y \exists z (x \not = y \land x \not = z \land y \not = z \land \neg \exists w (w \not = x \land w \not = y \land w \not = z))$

or, equivalently: $\exists x \exists y \exists z (x \not = y \land x \not = z \land y \not = z \land \forall w (w = x \lor w = y \lor w = z))$

Etc.

Interestingly, we see that in the second half of the statement, we no longer get $n+1 \choose 2$ (non-)identity claims, but merely $n$ (non-)identity claims, because we end up saying: once you have your $n$ different objects, then any object is one of the $n$ objects, so you can't have any more than $n$.  This is an idea that we can use to write the 'at least' and 'at most' claims more efficiently as well:

**'At most $n$' (Method 2)**

As just observed, we can say that there are exactly $n$ objects by saying that if you already have $n$ different objects, you can't get any other object. But to say that there are 'at most' $n$ objects, we don't have to require those $n$ objects to be different: we can simply say that we can pick $n$ objects, that may or may not be different, such that there is no object that is different from all those. So:

'There is at most $1$ object' : $\exists x \forall y \ y = x$

"There are at most $2$ objects" : $\exists x \exists y \forall z (z = x \lor z = y)$

Note that this is not claiming that $x$ and $y$ are different ... but they could be. Hence, you can have $1$ or $2$ different objects, but you definitely can't have $3$ or more!

"There are at most $3$ objects" : $\exists x \exists y \exists z \forall w (w = x \lor w = y \lor w = z)$

Etc.

So, in general, the claim is that there are $n$ objects such that every object has to be one of those objects, and that means that you can't have more than $n$ objects.

The nice thing about this expression is that it uses exactly $n$ identity statements, so it is quite a bit more efficient to write than the first method for expressing 'at most', especially for large $n$.

**'At least $n$' (Method 2)**

We pointed out earlier that 'at most $n$' is the negation of 'at least $n+1$', but that also means that 'at least $n+1$' is the negation of 'at most $n$'.

So:

"There are at least 2 P's": $\neg \exists x \forall y \ y = x$ which is equivalent to $\forall x \exists y \ y \not = x$

The latter statement says that for whatever object $x$ I pick, I can always find a different object. So, you need at least $2$ objects to make this true.

"There are at least $3$ objects": $\neg \exists x \exists y \forall z (z = x \lor z = y)$ which is equivalent to: $\forall x \forall y \exists z (z \not = x \land z \not= y)$

Etc.

So, to say that there are at least $n$ objects, we can say that no matter how you pick $n-1$ objects, you can always find an object different from all those. And, once again, this method saves us a lot of writing: only $n-1$ identity claims.

**'Exactly $n$' (Method 3)**

In the second method for 'exactly n', we saw that a claim like "There are exactly $3$ objects" translated into:

$\exists x \exists y \exists z (x \not = y \land x \not = z \land y \not = z \land \forall w (w = x \lor w = y \lor w = z))$

Thus, while in the second half we reduce the number of identity statements in comparison to the first method, we still get $3 \choose 2$ non-identity claims in the first half. Especially for large $n$ then, the most efficient way to express 'exactly $n$' seems to be the conjunction of the efficient ways to expressing 'at least $n$' and 'at most $n$'. That is:

"There are exactly $3$ objects" : $\forall x \forall y \exists z (z \not = x \land z \not= y) \land \exists x \exists y \exists z \forall w (w = x \lor w = y \lor w = z))$

"There are exactly $4$ objects" : $\forall x \forall y \forall z \exists w (w \not = x \land w \not = y \land w \not = z) \land \exists x \exists y \exists z \exists w \forall v (v = x \lor v = y \lor v = z \lor v = w))$

This method will have $2n-1$ (non-)identity claims.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can do it for $x=2$: $$\exists a\exists b(\neg(a=b)\wedge \forall c(c=a\vee c=b)).$$ I'll leave it to you to figure out why this works and how to generalize to arbitrary values of $x$.

Comment: But what if there are greater than x things in the domain of discourse?

Comment: Then the statement will be false...I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: For any finite number of elements, there exists exactly n things. Where n is equal to a long positive integer.

Comment: @AnonymousBambi Eric's shown you how to do this for $n=2$ (do you understand why the sentence he wrote is true iff there are exactly $2$ elements in the domain of discourse?). Can you see how to do this for an arbitrary $n$? How about $n=3$?

Comment: So the formula doest change. This formula works for any value of n?